# swift firebase query returns null with currentUser?.uid

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
let userID  = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
ref.child("players").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
    print("DICT VALUE",value)
})
```

I'm trying to get the profile of my signed in user. My issue is that if is use the variable userID 
`let userID  = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid`
the snapshot is null. Returns this `Snap (feoMdSquBSMHFXcPhZKbpsIGlKe2) <null>`

if I use the literal string `let userID = "feomdsqubsmhfxcphzkbpsiglke2"`for the userID child I get the expected return

```
Snap (feomdsqubsmhfxcphzkbpsiglke2) {
    currentSelected = 0;
    email = "2@yahoo.com";
    uid = feoMdSquBSMHFXcPhZKbpsIGlKe2;
    username = "player 2";
}
```

I can confirm the userID is valid

```
let userID  = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
print(userID!)
```

returns `feoMdSquBSMHFXcPhZKbpsIGlKe2`

here is the data that is stored

```
{
  "players" : {
    "feomdsqubsmhfxcphzkbpsiglke2" : {
      "currentSelected" : false,
      "email" : "2@yahoo.com",
      "uid" : "feoMdSquBSMHFXcPhZKbpsIGlKe2",
      "username" : "player 2"
    },
    "o4azcazrxjqc3toybykk0ghbd9o2" : {
      "currentSelected" : false,
      "email" : "1@yahoo.cm",
      "uid" : "O4aZCAZrXJQc3TOYbykK0ghbD9O2",
      "username" : "player 1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have no data in the database at the location you're trying to read.  What were you expecting in the snapshot instead of null?

Comment: i edited my answer to show the stored data. my expected result is also in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Firebase Database keys are case sensitive. In your database, your userID is:

```
feomdsqubsmhfxcphzkbpsiglke2
```

However, the actual userID of whatever user you are signed in as is:

```
feoMdSquBSMHFXcPhZKbpsIGlKe2
```

Try this:

```
let userID = feoMdSquBSMHFXcPhZKbpsIGlKe2
ref.child("players").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
    print("DICT VALUE",value)
})
```

and see what it gives you. If it doesn't work, you know that you have to watch the case of all your characters.

Comment: thanks! I knew I was missing something. When I first started playing around with this I had been using usernames as node ID's and was using a `.lowercased()` when inserting the username. I switched to using the real ID and I still had that `.lowercased()` on it there but was applying it to the real userID.